# Ruby Factory Girl Creating Multiple Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, mocking, factory, factory-bot

I am a newcomer to using Factory Girl and I feel I may have some misunderstandings about how it is suppose to work and how I am supposed to use it.  Here is a snippet of the problem code.

```
FactoryGirl.define do                      
   factory :li_store , :class => Store do   
   ...store stuff...blah...blah         
end                                      

factory :li_line_item_stores_two,:class=>LineItemsStore do   
   association :store, :factory=>:li_store                    
   association :line_item , :factory=>:li_line_item_two                                                         
end                                                             
factory :li_line_item_stores_three,:class=>LineItemsStore do 
   association :store :factory => :li_store                                   
   association :line_item , :factory => :li_line_item_three                                                 
end
```

Now if I access :li_line_item_stores_two and :li_line_item_stores_two each one has a different object for its store property.  For my test I need both objects to have the same store object.

Does anyone know what facet of FactoryGirl I am missing or how I should go about making sure both objects both reference the same store object ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to define *baseline* objects and attributes in your factories.rb file. You don't want to define a bunch of different identical versions of an object. Instead, factories.rb should look something like:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :li_store do 
    whatever
  end

  factory :li_line_item do
    whatever
  end

  factory :li_line_item_store do
    association :store, :factory => :li_store
    association :line_item, :factory => :li_line_item
  end
end
```

Those attributes are then overridable (or can be left with baseline values) in your tests:

```
def test_something
  store = Factory(:li_store)
  li_line_item_store_one = Factory(:li_line_item_store, :store => store)
  li_line_item_store_two = Factory(:li_line_item_store, :store => store)
end
```

With the above, you now have two li_line_item_store instances with different line items and the same store.

Comment: Thanks Tom.  That was it.  I have to wrap my head around the idea of what you said, that FactoryGirl creates baseline objects, then you slightly modify them for your test.  My testing code looks like this now and works as planned    store = Factory( :li_store )
    customer = Factory( :li_customer  , :store =>store  )
    line_item_store_one = Factory( :li_line_item_stores_one , :store =>store )
    line_item_store_two = Factory( :li_line_item_stores_two , :store =>store  )
    line_item_store_three = Factory( :li_line_item_stores_three , :store =>store )